# Creating a linked list in c++ (array of stucts is not working)

Tags: c++

So i was given a task to write a small print function to the linked list. I dont have any troubles with that(i guess), however i cannot create the list itself. I have tried allocating and linking the members of the list as soon as the user has entered their values, but i have got a lot of troubles assigning pointers to non existing members. So i have decided to get all the members` data at the beginning and link them after. The trouble i have right now is that for some reason when writing data to a dynamic array of structs the data is written only to the first member, although i dont have any errors and the syntax seems to look okaish.
Here is my code:

```
typedef int ELMNT;
typedef struct list
{
    ELMNT element;
    struct list * next;
}DLIST;

DLIST createList()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the length of an array: ";
    int arrLength;
    std::cin >> arrLength;
    int integer;
    std::cin >> integer;
    DLIST mylist;
    mylist.element = 0;
    mylist.element = integer;

    DLIST* listptr = new DLIST[arrLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> integer;
        listptr[arrLength].element = integer;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << listptr[arrLength].element;
    }

    return mylist;
}

int main()
{
    createList();
}
```

TL:DR:
Lines 3 to 8 are given by the task. 
I need to create a dynamic linked list.
The problem is that `listptr[arrLength].element = integer;` is not behaving as expected(not working at all). Any ideas? It seems to be some kind of syntax error or typo but i cannot solve it for and hour and a half.

EDIT:Oh thanks to the comments i see that next are not initialized when creating. How to do i initialize them? With NULL?

Comment: Why are you returning `DLIST` by value instead of a pointer?

Comment: When initializing the array none of the `next` pointers are initialized.

Comment: Please explain "[...] is not behaving as expected(not working at all)". How did you check that? What exactly is not behaving as expected?

Comment: @tadman Hmm, nice idea, will try returning a pointer

Comment: The C++ way would be a proper `class` and flyweight objects that are cheap to copy. This use of a `struct` is like *fancy C*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you are trying to do what you are doing, your code looks nothing like a linked list, but the errors are here

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> integer;
    listptr[arrLength].element = integer;
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> integer;
    listptr[i].element = integer;
}
```

and (same error really)

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
{
    std::cout << listptr[arrLength].element;
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
{
    std::cout << listptr[i].element;
}
```

Comment: next is not assigned so isn't really a list :)

Comment: I cant believe it was such a simple typo. Guess i need some sleep. I feel bad posting such an obvious mistake here. Anyway thank you kind stranger for spending time to help me. So bad there is noone nearby to review my code and find this things) I`ll mark your code as an aswer as soon as possible.

Comment: @CuteDoge01 More coffee, not more sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote
`listPtr[arrLength].element`
Instead of `listPtr[i].element`

(In both the printing and the assignment)

BTW this is dynamic array, not a linked list.

Comment: idk why but it is so called in the task. It really is a dynamic array.